# Confusion about a step down transformer use

Tags: transformer

This might sound a dumb question but I couldn't find an answer myself. I have come across [this](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/din-rail-panel-mount-transformers/5357828/) transformer. It has selectable I guess primary 215V to 400V, and a fixed secondary 115V. I know that nominal mains is around 115V in the US.

I first thought It is to step down lets say European nominal mains to US standard 115V. But then I though in what scenario can this be used. Theres is an ocean between two continents.

Can you give me a practical example/reason when could this be beneficial to use in the US?

Comment: YOu do realize that link is to a site in the United Kingdom right.

Comment: @Trevor_G Can this be used as step-down in the US and step-up in the UK? Both ways can be used? Someone mentioned frequency matters.

Comment: If it was built for 50 HZ, as in U.K., then 60 HZ in the USA will make it a tiny bit more efficient. A transformer made in the USA will be less efficient in the U.K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the USA there are various common AC (60 Hz) voltages distributed to residences and business. These voltages are typically either three-phase (industrial & commercial customers) or single-phase (residential customers and small businesses). The single-phase residential is nominally 230 volts line to line, and 115 volts neutral-ground to each line. This is fairly universal across the USA for residences.

In the business and industrial sector there are many more types of distributed voltages, most of which are three-phase. Some common voltages are 240 and 440. (these are all 60 cycle, and expressed as RMS voltages) There are other higher voltages distributed to industrial customers, again typically three-phase.

So, to answer your question, when you need to power a 115 volt device, and all that is available is 220 or 440, this is one situation where the transformer you reference would come into play.

In general, a 50 Hz transformer can be used with 60 Hz power, but a 60 Hz cannot be used with 50 Hz power. So, that's another factor that might come into play if you wanted to use an "American" transformer in Europe.

Comment: Regarding your example: Can it can also be the case: when you need to power a 230 volt device, and all that is available is 115, this is one situation??

Comment: looks like it is meant to power control devices in an industrial control panel ... contactor coils, timers, etc. ... it also provides isolation

Comment: @jsotola Aren't all transformers isolation  transformers by nature (since all transformers primary and secondary are magnetically coupled)? What is the difference?

Comment: it separates the controlling side of the panel from the high voltage power side ... sort of like an opto-isolator separating a 120Vac dimmer from a low voltage controller

Comment: as long as the secondary winding is isolated and is not connected to chassis ground in any way, you could be grounded to the chassis and you could touch one of the the output terminals of the secondary without getting killed, because there would not be a completed circuit through your body

Comment: @GenzoWakabayashi NO, not all transformers are isolating. See [Autotransformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autotransformer)

Comment: @pumpman Common residential power in the USA (nominally 115/230) is two-phase in that each line-to-neutral 115v side of the delivered 230 line-to-line voltage is 180 degrees out phase with respect to the other line-to-neutral side of the pair. This must be  the case for them to add up to 230 volts (RMS). Further, the 230/115 triad of wires is sourced from a center-tapped pole transformer, which by its topological nature defines the 180 degrees phase relationship of line-to-neutral-to-line. Taken as a single pair the line-to-line 230 volt feed is single-phase.

Comment: @GenzoWakabayashi You probably wouldn't use the transformer you linked to for such an application because it's secondary is only rated for 115 VAC. However, you can easily find a transformer that can step-up 115 VAC to 230 VAC in the electrical component marketplace. You might be able to hook up your example xformer in reverse (secondary as primary) to achieve the step-up you require. However, there are certain precautions you must take when reversing primary and secondary. Too much to explain here. It's possible, but not advisable as a universal practice.